# Is stress test with junit possible?

Tags: junit, automated-tests, stress-testing

I'm new to java and Junit, I need to stress test a set of web services, now for each web service I have a test like this:

```
@Test
public void webServiceTest() {
Integer firstParameter=0;
Integer secondParameter=9;
List<GeoArea> sampleList = kitDAO.myWebServiceToTest(firstParameter, secondParameter);
Assert.assertNotNull(sampleList);
Assert.assertTrue(sampleList.size() > 0);
}
```

Is there a way to call this test 100 time simultaneously with different parameters? I would create 100 thread, pass to them 100 different set of parameters and start the thread simultaneously. Do you think this is possible? How would you do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

[JUnitPerf](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html) provides a LoadTest wrapper to run the same test multiple times.  I don't think you can pass it different parameters, but you could add that part yourself.  Have a static list of your 100 parameters and then have each instance of the test remove one value from that static list.